# Migrating ArcPy scripts from ArcGIS 9.3 to 10?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, migration

What changes are needed to migrate scripts from the ArcGis 9.x environment/gp-object to the ArcGis 10/arcpy environment?

Can anyone provide a good overview what the changes are?

Can someone share pitfalls etc from their own experience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GeoChalkboard](http://www.geospatialtraining.com/blog/?p=1961) can give you a good overview of the changes!

Here's the list, but check it out for more detail:

1. Replace the import statement
2. Replace all gp. with arcpy.
3. Check your capitalization.
4. The result tool is different.
5. Replace any del gp statements.
6. The overwrite tool is different.
7. Import the env module from arcpy.
8. List item

Comment: One little comment: _2. Replace all gp. with arcpy_ isn't really needed if you assign your import to gp, lik so: `import arcpy` `gp = arcpy`. Which also makes _5._ obsolete, as well.