# Is it possible to run ArcGIS 9.3 python script for ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-9.3

I need to translate python 2.5 script for ArcGIS 9.3 to python 2.7 for ArcGIS 10.3.

Our office has now all computers with ArcGIS 10.3. So, I need to translate these scripts to arcgis 10.3. 
Could anyone give me some information please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you have to put some effort into it. Sometimes even the spelling of an 10.0 and 10.3 script is different.

Check this question for a good overview: [Migrating ArcPy scripts from ArcGIS 9.3 to 10?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37464/migrate-python-scripts-from-9-3-to-arcgis10).

I would also recommend you to check out the data access module ([arcpy.da](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#/na/018w00000008000000/)) mainly for cursors, which is much faster than the regular cursors.